# Search SQL for most common words

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, dreamweaver

I'm currently in the process of setting my first website implementing SQL.

I wish to use one of the columns from a table to identify the most commonly used word in the columns.

So, that is to say:

```
// TABLE = STUFF

// COLUMN0 = Hello there
// COLUMN1 = Hello I am Stuck
// COLUMN2 = Hi dude
// COLUMN3 = What's Up?
```

Therefore I wish to return a string of 'HELLO' as the most common word.

I should say I am using PHP and Dreamweaver to communicate with the SQL server, so I am placing the SQL query with in the relevant SQL line of a Recordset, with the result to be consequently placed on the site.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: What you could do is query the table, and explode the strings into arrays, then compare the arrays while keeping count of `$word => $count` and boom, you will find the most common words, in an easily sortable associative array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the most common words in PHP like this:

```
function extract_common_words($string, $stop_words, $max_count = 5) {
  $string = preg_replace('/ss+/i', '', $string);
  $string = trim($string); // trim the string
  $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z -]/', '', $string); // only take alphabet characters, but keep the spaces and dashes too…
  $string = strtolower($string); // make it lowercase

  preg_match_all('/\b.*?\b/i', $string, $match_words);
  $match_words = $match_words[0];

  foreach ( $match_words as $key => $item ) {
      if ( $item == '' || in_array(strtolower($item), $stop_words) || strlen($item) <= 3    ) {
          unset($match_words[$key]);
      }
  }  

  $word_count = str_word_count( implode(" ", $match_words) , 1); 
  $frequency = array_count_values($word_count);
  arsort($frequency);

  //arsort($word_count_arr);
  $keywords = array_slice($frequency, 0, $max_count);
  return $keywords;
}
```

Comment: I am totally new to PHP and SQL. So, how do I implement this with the data held in the SQL database?

Comment: That is to say, do I place the data in a recordset and then pass the function on that recordset string? If so, how do I get the code above to read that recordset? Or am I on the wrong track? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have worked out how to apply the function. using echo and calling the items from the output array I have got what I needed. Thank you